# What does \empty do?

Tags: tex-core

What does it do and what are its applications? I am currently testing the subtitle of my beamer presentation for its string length to decide about line spacings. Could it be simpler using `\empty`?

If I just try `\empty{word}`, it seems that nothing happens. Of course, I do not expect to get a string length, but I thought that I could check the title for being empty or not.

This is how I add space by checking beamer's subtitle:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\StrLen{\insertsubtitle}[\subtitlelen]

\ifnum\subtitlelen>0{
    \vskip0.2cm
}\fi
```

I try to clarify my question as requested in the comments: I thought that I could check for `\empty`. `\StrLen` is easy to understand because you can output that value as text. However, this does not work for `\empty` so I wondered how one would use it to accomplish the same task.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel defines `\let\empty\@empty` and earlier `\def\@empty{}`. So it is a macro without arguments that expands to nothing.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that I cannot use it for the purpose I thought I could?

Comment: You can use `\empty` and `\@empty` to test whether an argument or another macro is empty ("string" length zero). There are also packages that do this and eTeX solutions that do this without using `\[@]empty`. The sequence `\empty{word}` is nothing special. In fact, `{word}` is not an argument here but simply the letters `word` in a group since `\empty` doesn't take an argument. What do you want to know? What `\empty` does? It does nothing, see the linked question. Do you want to know about string lengths? Check the `xstring` package ([tag:xstring]) or related questions on TeX.sx.

Comment: For me, your question is not clear. Maybe an example, a use-case and a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help us help you.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you, I clarified my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\empty` is defined in the LaTeX kernel by

```
% latex.ltx, line 122:
\def\@empty{}
% latex.ltx, line 441:
\let\empty\@empty
```

Actually the kernel macro is `\@empty`, but `\empty` is equivalent and is in the kernel for backward compatibility, because Plain TeX uses `\empty`.

When you expand `\empty` you get nothing at all, so

```
\empty{word}
```

is just equivalent to typing

```
{word}
```

which is not different, under normal circumstances, to typing `word` without braces.

What's the use of `\empty` (better `\@empty`)? If you want to see whether the replacement text of a (parameterless) macro has no tokens, you can do

```
\ifx\mymacro\empty
  <text to be used if \mymacro expands to nothing>
\else
  <text to be used otherwise>
\fi
```

A frequent use case is when you want to test whether an optional argument is empty. For instance

```
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\mymacro}[1][]{%
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@empty
     no optional argument (or \mymacro[])
   \else
     do something with #1
   \fi
 }
```

However, with e-TeX extensions available, it's better to use

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     no optional argument (or \mymacro[])
   \else
     do something with #1
   \fi
 }
```

The main usage of `\@empty` in the kernel is for initializing macros to a default value, so the construct

```
\let\cs\@empty
```

is used many times. During processing, `\cs` will receive various values, and macros can test whether `\cs` is in its initial state or not.

Another important use in in the definition of `\@array`, where

```
\let\par\@empty
```

is found, which allows empty lines in `array` or `tabular` environments.

Comment: Although I already upvoted your answer, I'd like to say that this is an excellent answer. Thank you for showing me the uses of \empty!