Conditional format in \listofkeytheorems for named theorems
In the "List of Named Results" produced by the keytheorems command \listofkeytheorems, the option note-code=\mythmlistform{#1} causes the namedtheorem entry to omit the parentheses.
Questions:

There is an extra space at the beginning of the "Pythagorean Theorem" namedtheorem entry in the list of theorems, presumably because of the elided left parenthesis. How can that extra space be eliminated?
Is there a simpler way to set up the test than using the command \mythmlistform (which is based upon https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147883/13492)?

Here is the source:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[thmtools-compat]{keytheorems} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mythmlistform}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     {#1}
   \else
     {(#1)}
   \fi
 }
\keytheoremlistset{
  title=List of Named Results,
  note-code=\mythmlistform{#1},
  }

% Theorem-like enviroments  
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \MurrayCheckIfEmptyNote
  {
    \tl_if_empty:NT \l__keythms_thmuse_note_tl
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \__keythms_thm_addcontentsdata:nnnn \use_none:nnnn }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\mdseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=swapnumber,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  preheadhook={%
    \let\eminnershape\normalfont
    \MurrayCheckIfEmptyNote}
]{thmstyle}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=swapnumber,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  preheadhook={%
    \let\eminnershape\normalfont
    \MurrayCheckIfEmptyNote}
]{namedthmstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}
 
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{The section}

\begin{theorem}[A key theorem]
Some theorem text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem with no note.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of upon the other two sides.
\end{namedtheorem}

\listofkeytheorems[ignoreall,show={theorem,namedtheorem}]

\end{document}


(The definition and use of \MurrayCheckIfEmptyNote comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728259/13492 .)

So the first entry should be Theorem (A key theorem), correct?

@mbert: Right, the first entry should include the parentheses: I only noticed after posting that my attempt had also removed parentheses.

Set note-code={#1} and use format-code to control the entry format. You can use \tl_if_empty:eTF to test if the "name" is empty (note the e-type expansion is necessary). Use onlynamed to print only those theorems with notes.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[thmtools-compat]{keytheorems} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \MurrayListFormat #1#2#3
  {
    \numberline{#2}
    \tl_if_empty:eTF { #1 } { #3 } { #1~(#3) }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\keytheoremlistset{
  title=List of Named Results,
  note-code={#1},
  format-code=\MurrayListFormat{#1}{#2}{#3},
  }
  
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\mdseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=swapnumber,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  preheadhook={\let\eminnershape\normalfont}
]{thmstyle}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=swapnumber,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  preheadhook={\let\eminnershape\normalfont}
]{namedthmstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}
 
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{The section}

\begin{theorem}[A key theorem]
Some theorem text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem with no note.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
The square upon the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of upon the other two sides.
\end{namedtheorem}

\listofkeytheorems[ignoreall,show={theorem,namedtheorem},onlynamed]

\end{document}


